# ¿Hay alguna forma de configurar Wordpress para que se actualice de forma automática? ¿Aportaría esto algo a la seguridad?

Tags: wordpress, seguridad

En sitios Wordpress donde se agrega contenido nuevo con poca frecuencia pueden pasar semanas o meses sin entrar como administrador. Hasta que no se entra como administrador no es posible saber qué actualizaciones hay (de Wordpress, de temas, de plugins), ni tampoco es posible actualizar.

Por eso me pregunto si existe alguna forma de actualizar Wordpress sin tener que entrar como administrador y si automatizar ese proceso aportaría algo a la seguridad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisamente de cara a la seguridad, desde la versión 3.7 Wordpress permite automatizar algunos procesos delicados que, si tardásemos semanas o meses en hacerlos podrían poner en riesgo nuestro sitio.

La funcionalidad en presentada en estos términos en [`codex.wordpress.org`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates#Update_Types):

> Las actualizaciones en segundo plano automáticas se introdujeron en
>   WordPress 3.7 en un esfuerzo por promover **una mejor seguridad** y
>   para optimizar la experiencia de actualización en general. De manera
>   predeterminada, solo las versiones menores, como las de mantenimiento
>   y seguridad, y las actualizaciones de archivos de traducción están
>   habilitadas en la mayoría de los sitios. En casos especiales, los
>   complementos y temas pueden ser actualizados.

Allí mismo se explica que las actualizaciones automáticas son de varios tipos, y se pueden configurar de dos maneras:

### 1. Vía `wp-config.php`

- #### *El núcleo (core) de Wordpress*

Habría que definir la constante **`WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE`**, con tres parámetros posibles:

- Valor **`true`**: todas las actualizaciones de desarrollo, menores y mayores están habilitadas
- Valor  **`false`**: todas las actualizaciones de desarrollo, menores y mayores están deshabilitadas
- Valor **`'minor'`**: las actualizaciones menores están habilitadas, el desarrollo y las actualizaciones importantes están deshabilitadas

Ejemplo:

```
/*
   *Activa actualizaciones automáticas para el núcelo de WP
*/
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );
```

---

### 2. Vía filtros

- #### *A. El núcleo (core) de Wordpress*

Para activar las actualizaciones automáticas del core:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_core', '__return_true' );
```

Hay dos funciones abreviadas integradas en WordPress que te permitirán habilitar o deshabilitar tipos específicos de actualizaciones principales con líneas de código únicas. Ellos son `__return_true` y `__return_false`. Aquí hay algunos filtros de ejemplo:

```
/*Activa actualizaciones de desarrollo*/
add_filter( 'allow_dev_auto_core_updates', '__return_true' );

/*Activa actualizaciones menores*/    
add_filter( 'allow_minor_auto_core_updates', '__return_true' );

/*Activa actualizaciones mayores*/
add_filter( 'allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_true' );
```

- #### *B. Actualización automática de plugins y temas*

Este es también un punto neurálgico de la seguridad. Wordpress permite establecer actualizaciones automáticas sólo a nivel de filtros.

De forma predeterminada, las actualizaciones de fondo automáticas solo se realizan para complementos y temas en casos especiales, según lo determinado por la respuesta de la API de WordPress.org, que está controlada por el equipo de seguridad de WordPress para parchear vulnerabilidades críticas. Para habilitar o deshabilitar las actualizaciones en todos los casos, puede aprovechar el filtro `auto_update_$type`, donde `$type` se reemplazaría con "`plugin`" o "`theme`".

Actualizaciones automáticas para todos los plugins:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
```

Actualizaciones automáticas para todos los temas:

```
add_filter ('auto_update_theme', '__return_true');
```

Puedes usar `__return_false` en lugar de `__return_true` para deshabilitar específicamente todas las actualizaciones de temas y complementos, incluso los controles de seguridad forzados del equipo de seguridad de WordPress.

Los filtros `auto_update_ $type` también permiten un control más preciso, ya que el elemento específico a actualizar también se pasa al filtro. Si deseas habilitar las actualizaciones automáticas solo para complementos específicos, entonces puede usar un código como este:

```
function auto_update_specific_plugins ( $update, $item ) {
    // Array of plugin slugs to always auto-update
    $plugins = array ( 
        'akismet',
        'buddypress',
    );
    if ( in_array( $item->slug, $plugins ) ) {
        return true; // Always update plugins in this array
    } else {
        return $update; // Else, use the normal API response to decide whether to update or not
    }
}
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', 'auto_update_specific_plugins', 10, 2 );
```

- #### *C. Actualizaciones de traducción a través de filtro*

Las actualizaciones de los archivos de traducción automática ya están habilitadas de forma predeterminada, al igual que las actualizaciones básicas menores.

Si quieres deshabilitar las actualizaciones de archivos de traducción, puedes usar:

```
add_filter ('auto_update_translation', '__return_false');
```

- #### *D. Deshabilitar correos electrónicos a través del filtro*

Cuando una actualización automática tiene éxito o falla, WordPress envía un correo electrónico de notificación a la dirección de correo electrónico proporcionada en Configuración -> General desde wordpress@yourdomain.com.

Para deshabilitar estos correos electrónicos de notificación de actualización, usa el siguiente filtro:

```
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
```

Este filtro también se puede usar para manipular correos electrónicos de actualización según el correo electrónico $type (éxito, fallo, crítico), el objeto de tipo de actualización `$core_update` o `$result`:

```
/* @param bool   $send        Enviar el email. Default true.
 * @param string $type        El tipo de email a enviar.
 *                            Puede ser uno de estos: 'success', 'fail', 'critical'.
 * @param object $core_update La oferta de actualización que se intentó.
 * @param mixed  $result      El resultado para la actualización del núcleo. Puede ser WP_Error.
 */
apply_filters( 'auto_core_update_send_email', true, $type, $core_update, $result );
```

---

**Enlaces:**

- [Configuring Automatic Background Updates (documentación oficial de WP)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates#Update_Types)
- [The definitive guide to disabling auto updates in WordPress 3.7](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/10/25/the-definitive-guide-to-disabling-auto-updates-in-wordpress-3-7/)
- [How Do I Configure Automatic Updates in WordPress 3.7?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120081/how-do-i-configure-automatic-updates-in-wordpress-3-7)
- [Información sobre el conflicto wp-cli](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/1310)